# PHP - if condition inside string

Tags: php, string, if-statement

An easy question to ask, hope not to stupid.

```
$var=0;
$condition="$var!=0";
if($condition) {
    # do something #
}
else {
    # do something else #
}
```

Obviously the code up there doesn't work as intended. Is there a nice way to obtain an if-condition from a string? Or do I have to parse the string in some disturbing way?

EDIT
I didn't explain myself very well.
The fact is that the string could contain any possible condition you can immagine es:

- $var > 0
- $var < 0
- $var == 0
- etc

I read this condition from an xml file as a string, so I don't know what I will find.

Comment: The first person to mention the four letter word starting with "e" is going to get a good, solid glare.  @Abaco, what is the larger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Charles: +1. Love the 'four-letter word starting with "e"'

Comment: The follow-up question is - why do you have the condition in an XML file? What does the condition represent? Can it really be anything, or can you enumerate the possibilities? And where do you get the XML file from (i.e. how secure are you some idiot didn't put in the condition saying `unlink($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`, or worse)?

Comment: A user describe a table in an xml file following a certain logic. One of the tags inside the xml-code should grant to the user the possibility to make some comparisons between numeric variables, therefore yes I can enumerate the different possibilities.
EDIT: I can't know the idiot's objectives, but to sanitize the input I should first know how to make the code capable of read it.

Comment: If you can enumerate them, it's better to do it that way; make a switch in your code and execute an appropriate comparison that is hard-coded in your PHP, based on values in XML, something like: `switch ($relation) { case ">=": $result = $var >= $standard; break; ... }` where `$relation` and `$standard` are from the XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because no one has posted it yet. Ask yourself what comparisons need to be made. If they're doing simple math operations you might want to have something in the schema like this.

```
<conditions>
  <notEqual var="var" value="0" />
</conditions>
```

It'll allow you to have multiple conditions, should be relatively simple to parse and convert to php code.

Comment: Exactly what I was saying. +1.

Comment: Uhm nice. Thinking about it I've only 6 possible comparisons. Thank you. +1

Comment: @Amadan didn't see your comment before. You might have wanted to put it in an answer (it was still a little different)

Comment: @Abaco Thanks! Surprized me by accepting it. I just didn't want to see this post close with only one non-eval "Answer" available

Answer (score 4):

The [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function is the easy way out here. E.g.:

```
if(eval($condition)) {
    # do something #
}
else {
    # do something else #
}
```

It must be stressed that `eval()` is evil. It is very easy to make a website extremely insecure using `eval()`, even if you really know what you're doing. In particular, even if you're sure the code is safe *now*, it might not be so after you add a few features in totally different parts of the code.

That said `eval()` has its uses, particularly in quick-and-dirty single use scripts like migration scripts.

If you're writing a world-facing website, you need to take ****extreme**** care if using `eval()`. Very often, the necessary amount of care is more difficult than implementing some non-`eval()` solution.

Comment: You were the first.  ***GLARE***.  `eval` is evil!  If you've found a problem where `eval` is the solution, `eval` is not the solution!

Comment: You said it yourself: `eval` is evil. Sometimes it's the least evil option, in which case it is the appropriate one. Just because a tool is really easy to misuse doesn't mean it should never be used.

Comment: @Charles I have to agree. Though I understand that he is just providing a possible solution so you can't hate completely. But I really would have to wonder what circumstance someone would find themselves in where you would have to use an eval. Especially for a seemingly easy circumstance.

Comment: I used a PHP-based CMS named Ariadne, which has user-editable pieces of code, in a restricted PHP language. It pre-processed the code to insert `$this->` in front of every function call except those on the approved list, similarly with variables, then `eval`-ed it. Of course there were gotchas - it's obvious you don't put `eval` on the approved list, but you better not put `preg_replace` on it either since it's `eval` in disguise. However, it was a good hack, and did what it did surprisingly well. It doesn't change the fact that `eval` is Evil, just goes to show even Evil does good sometimes.

Comment: It really depends on the circumstance. In a single-use script that you will use to, e.g. reformat some of your data files, `eval()` can save you a good deal of time. On an internet-facing website it should almost always be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

why not just do:

```
$var = 0;
if ($var != 0){
    # do something #
}
else {
    # do something else #
}
```

EDIT: Or even

```
$var = 0;
$condition = 0
if ($var != $condition){
    # do something #
}
else {
    # do something else #
}
```

Comment: He edited the question after I had already made this post. Now with the edit it does.

Answer (score 0):

1. The contents of your `$condition` are not `$var!=0`, but `0=0` (due to `$` not being escaped (`\$`) within double quotes.
2. You can do this with `eval` function.
3. However, `eval` is Evil. Ask yourself if you really need to do this. If there is any other way, take it.

Answer (score -1):

OK, you could use evil Eval. But if your condition is actually as simple as you propose, you could just use a regex to test the condition... No eval necessary.