# How to use if condition inside string in php

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I want to know if there is a way to use something like this:

```
$t1=1;
$t2=2;
$t3="$t1>$t2";

if($t3)
   echo "Greater";
else
   echo "Smaller";
```

This will evaluate to true as $t3 is a string, but that's wrong!!!

So is there a way to include the if condition inside string.

I heard that we can use eval for this:
[PHP - if condition inside string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191911/php-if-condition-inside-string)

But how is this possible???

Comment: look on the answer in the link you attached , this is exactly the same example eval()

Comment: Why not `if ($t1 > $t2) echo "Greater" else echo "Smaller"`?

Comment: sample included in the link was not working for me So, I thought of asking it again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it should work, given the PHP [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) page.

```
$t1=1;
$t2=2;
$t3="return $t1>$t2;";

if(eval($t3))
   echo "Greater";
else
   echo "Smaller";
```

Answer (score 3):

For that, you don't need to evaluate a string. Just write it as a raw condition, and it'll give you a boolean which you can evaluate as is in the if condition:

```
$t3 = $t1 > $t2;
```

By the way, the `else` in your code will evaluate if `$t1` and `$t2` are equal. You can use an `else if` to take care of that, but it's just something I thought I'd point out.

Comment: OP specifically wants it to be in a string,.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, an else if will be better, I wrote it as a general rule.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you don't heed that and this question come out from bad design.
Why not to make it just

```
if ($t1>$t2) echo "greater";
```

Comment: I decided to use eval() which seems to be the better solution.